# How to select anchor tag which are inside of a Paragraph tag?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to individually select the first anchor tag and last anchor tag of the `<p>` tag.

```html
<div class="not01">
  <img src="/assets/images/avatar-mark-webber.webp" alt="Mark Webber image">
  <p> <a href="#">Mark Webber </a> reacted to your recent post <a href="#">My first tournament today!</a></p>
  <span>1m ago</span>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean select? explain more, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `:first-child` and `:last:child` css selectors.

```css
p a:first-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}

p a:last-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a>This anchor is the first child of its parent (p).</a>
  <a>This anchor is the second child of its parent (p).</a>
  <a>This anchor is the third child of its parent (p).</a>
</p>
```

Comment: This only works if the `a` is **also** the `:last-child`, it doesn't work if there's another subsequent element after the last `a`. [Consider using `p a:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) instead of `p a:last-child` (and vice-versa for `:first-of-type` vs `:first-child`).